# REGEX for multiple words and all caps in C

Tags: c

I'm struggling a bit with a regular expression for capturing these parts of the word - i've given an example of text strings with special cases

Greg **VAN AVERMAET**"

Zdenek **STYBAR**"

Laurens **DE VREESE**"

Lars Ytting **BAK**"

I've made the text i want bold.

Can anyone help me create the regex for this? i've been struggling with it, with a friend, for quite a while.

And then it needs to be put in a control string in C.

Comment: Experiment. I recommend https://regex101.com/ for it.

Comment: in `a b c` sometimes you want `b c`, sometimes only `c` ... not very deterministic

Comment: If these last names are always the same, I would not recommend Regex but just a simple string compare.

Comment: The file name contains 700 individual people.

Comment: I've experimented with it on a regEx'r building site for 3 hours XD